# How every class is inherited Object class?

Tags: java, inheritance

How come every class in Java is inherited from the class called `java.lang.Object`, even though we do not `extend` it explicitly?

What is happening behind the scenes?

Comment: I always wonder *Why `A` comes before `B`?*

Comment: @HarryJoy though sarcasm is not appreciated in SO, +1 for humor :D

Answer (score 1):

All Classes in the Java Platform are Descendants of Object. Object class has no superclass, every class has one and only one direct superclass (single inheritance). In the absence of any other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of Object.

See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Answer (score 1):

This was a design decision that the makers of Java went with, back in the mists of time.  I believe it's so that every object comes with implementations of a handful of basic methods (hashCode, equals, wait, notify), without them having to be specifically written.  This has a whole load of benefits - having implementations for hashCode and equals makes things like Sets and HashMaps work nicely; having implementations for notify and wait makes multi-threaded programming much easier.

As far as what's happening behind the scenes - well, I guess you'd need to look into the source code of either the compiler or the JVM.  However, there's really not much point.  Most Java developers are comfortable with the fact that every object is an Object - it's one of those things that make Java what it is.

Comment: I agree. But I am not able to find out the exact class that implements this concept. Can you tell the exact class name where the actual work is done?

Answer (score 0):

Well, because **every class** inherits from **Object**. It is redundant.

Comment: Yes. I understand every class is subclass of Object. But it should be designed/coded somewhere to do this. Where is it? In which class they did this work?

Comment: @Srinivasan This concept is explained clearly in the JDK source code.